# Setting transparency for no data in raster in geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, style, transparency-opacity, nodata

I have a raster published in my geoserver with  default raster style as below

```
<NamedLayer>
<Name>default_raster</Name>
<UserStyle>
<!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
  <Title>Default Raster</Title>
  <Abstract>A sample style that draws a raster, good for displaying imagery</Abstract>
  <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
  <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering rasters -->
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>rule1</Name>
      <Title>Opaque Raster</Title>
      <Abstract>A raster with 100% opacity</Abstract>
      <RasterSymbolizer>
        <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
      </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

And my imagery looks like 
[image]

Which has black color set for no data. I want to make the no data to transparent. How that can be done?

Comment: Perhaps this page might help: [Styling Raster data](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/styling_raster.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with SLD. Publish your imagery as a image mosaic and change the "input transparent color" to black instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this question is still relevant to anyone, but I found a solution using YSLD.  Check out the documentation on the [raster symbolizer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/symbolizers/raster.html) and note the "intervals" color ramp.  You can simply set the interval containing the no-data value to transparent.  For example, if your no-data value is something north of 36000:

```
title: Discrete Ramp'
feature-styles:
- name: raster
  rules:
  - name: raster
  - symbolizers:
    - raster:
        opacity: 1.0
        color-map:
          type: intervals
          entries:
          - ['#000000',0, 36000,'']
```

The format here is `[<color>,<transparency>,<cell value>,<symbol>]`. You can, of course, add more entries to symbolize other ranges of values.  I hope this helps, even though it's a few years too late. :)

Comment: That's also something you could do with SLD `ColorMap` elements: you define a `ColorMapEntry` with the `opacity` attribute set to `0`. I used this "trick" for my maps to set transparency!