# Setting up TIFF files for tiling in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have five GeoTIFF files that I have setup in GeoServer. I am displaying these on a OpenLayers map. I have tried some recommendations in the [data considerations](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/data.html), such as inner tiling and setting up overviews, however the performance seems lacking being that these aren't very large files. I was hoping I could get some feedback as to a good way to structure these TIFFs to optimize performance when tiling. See below the output for file info of the unaltered files:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 109320, 88072
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-10968941.448953511193395,5653006.415421720594168)
Pixel Size = (32.241277618252468,-32.241277618252468)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-10968941.449, 5653006.415) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Left  (-10968941.449, 2813452.613) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Upper Right (-7444324.980, 5653006.415) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Right (-7444324.980, 2813452.613) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Center      (-9206633.214, 4233229.514) ( 82d42'16.54"W, 35d30'31.36"N)
Band 1 Block=109320x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=THEMATIC




Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 109320, 88072
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-10968941.448953511193395,5653006.415421720594168)
Pixel Size = (32.241277618252475,-32.241277618252475)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-10968941.449, 5653006.415) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Left  (-10968941.449, 2813452.613) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Upper Right (-7444324.980, 5653006.415) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Right (-7444324.980, 2813452.613) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Center      (-9206633.214, 4233229.514) ( 82d42'16.54"W, 35d30'31.36"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 54660x44036, 27330x22018, 13665x11009, 6833x5505, 3417x2753, 1709x1377, 855x689, 428x345, 214x173
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=THEMATIC
```

`gdalinfo output.tif -stats:`

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 109320, 88072
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-10968941.448953511193395,5653006.415421720594168)
Pixel Size = (32.241277618252475,-32.241277618252475)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-10968941.449, 5653006.415) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Left  (-10968941.449, 2813452.613) ( 98d32' 8.44"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Upper Right (-7444324.980, 5653006.415) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 45d11'58.72"N)
Lower Right (-7444324.980, 2813452.613) ( 66d52'24.63"W, 24d29'30.51"N)
Center      (-9206633.214, 4233229.514) ( 82d42'16.54"W, 35d30'31.36"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=99.000, Mean=7.573, StdDev=17.275
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 54660x44036, 27330x22018, 13665x11009, 6833x5505, 3417x2753, 1709x1377, 855x689, 428x345, 214x173
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=THEMATIC
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=99
    STATISTICS_MEAN=7.5732497554581
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=17.27458624911
```

I tried the following:

- Tiled 256x256 and 512x512 -- This slowed down performance
- Added overviews(with average and bilinear resampling) -- This sped up performance on first load of course, however it filled in null values to the point that looked misrepresentative of the data (See images)

Raw image in GeoServer:
[image]
[image]

With overview:
[image]
[image]

Comment: that tiff is not tiled nor does it have overviews.

Comment: @IanTurton That is the unaltered TIFF file that I was posting for reference.

Comment: I updated the description with the options I have tried, along with some pictures of the map.

Comment: I would use tiles, compression and nearest neighbour for the overviews.

Comment: @IanTurton I was using the default levels for overviews with gdaladdo. Is this fine do you think? Also, I'll see how nearest neighbor looks.

Comment: Tiling is a must and so are the overview levels. You have a single band image `Band 1 Block=109320x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray` with white as nodata. That is not so common, it can well be that resampling with gdaladdo is changing pixel values so that they fall into another category. What kind of styles do you use for rendering that grayscale image? Could you share a small sample of your imagery?

Comment: @user30184 I updated the description with the gdalinfo for the tiff tiled 256x256 with overviews. I also added some zoomed in images so you can see the effects of the resampling. As for the styles, I'm not exactly sure. I am just using the defaults on GeoServer to create the layer and then hitting that from the OpenLayers UI.

Comment: What is the nature of that image? Metadata says it is thematic. Is it some classified measurement data or what? Is it something on top of that OpenStreetMap kind of map or the OSM-alike map itself? Does `gdalinfo your_image.tif -stats` print color table?

Comment: @user30184 These are storm surge data files from NOAA. The output of that is in the description.

Comment: @user30184 The storm surge is the black area around the coastal regions of the map

Comment: Could you provide link to such data? I gues that how nodata appears in those images is not typical and normal downsampling methods do not quite work. Using mask band instead of nodata could work better, but it may be that the mask band should not be downsampled at all. Mask polygons might be another option.

Comment: @user30184 Sorry for the delay. You can download the data [here](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/hazardmaps/US_SLOSH_MOM_Inundation.zip).

Answer (score 0):

The presence of null values and shown as black pixels in the image is because your NoData is represented as black by Geoserver.

See this post:
[Setting transparency for no data in raster in geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219145/setting-transparency-for-no-data-in-raster-in-geoserver)

To avoid that, either you transform your raw data using GDAL for not having such NoData values inside the raster and before uploading it to Geoserver, OR create a style in Geoserver for not representing the null values as black.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. If it were, wouldn't I see black all across the screen and not just where the resampling is taking place?